# How to move a google doc into a folder using Zend Gdata

Tags: zend-framework, gdata, gdata-api, zend-gdata

Hi Guys I am really struggling with moving a document from my root folder to another folder using zend gdata here is how i am trying to do it, but its not working.

```
$service = Zend_Gdata_Docs::AUTH_SERVICE_NAME;
$client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient($gUser, $gPass, $service);
$link = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/documents/private/full/spreadsheet:0AUFNVEpLOVg2U0E"; // Not real id for privacy purposes
$docs = new Zend_GData_Docs($client);

// Attach a category object of folder to this entry
// I have tried many variations of this including attaching label categories
$cat = new Zend_Gdata_App_Extension_Category('My Folder Name','http://schemas.google.com/docs/2007#folder');

$entry = $docs->getDocumentListEntry($link);
$entry->setCategory(array($cat));

$return = $docs->updateEntry($entry,$entry->getEditLink()->href);
```

When I run this I get No errors, but nothing seems to change, and the return data does not contain the new category.

**EDIT:**
Ok  I realised that its not the category but the link that decides which "collection" (folder) a resource belongs too. https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#managing_collections_and_their_contents says that each resource has as et of parent links, so I tried changing my code to do set link instead of set category, but this did not work.

```
$folder = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/documents/private/full/folder%3A0wSFA2WHc";
$rel = "http://schemas.google.com/docs/2007#parent";

$linkObj = new Zend_Gdata_App_Extension_Link($folder,$rel,'application/atom+xml', NULL,'Folder Name');
$links = $entry->getLink();
array_push($links,$linkObj);
$entry->setLink($links);

$return = $docs->updateEntry($entry,$entry->getEditLink()->href);
```

**EDIT: SOLVED [nearly]**
OK Here is how to move/copy, sort of, from one folder to another:
simpler than initially thought, but problem is it creates a reference and NOT a move! It now in both places at the same time....

```
// Folder you want to move too
$folder = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/folders/private/full/folder%asdsad";
$data = $docs->insertDocument($entry, $folder); // Entry is the entry you want moved using insert automatically assigns link & category for you...
```

Comment: first thing: the Zend_Gdata classes are not current they use the v2 api at https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/v2/developers_guide_protocol#SearchingDocs, the link you provided is for the v3 api.

Comment: Yes I am aware of that, but that link is the only documentation I have to go on at the moment, its all I have to try and figure out how to do it, the api still uses atom so it still works just, its just google's docs are so light on info, even the forum has many questions on how to do this without any satisfactory answers...https://groups.google.com/forum/embed/?place=forum/google-documents-list-api#!forum/google-documents-list-api. I do realise that Zend Gdata is older but it does everything else, its just the moving that seems to be an issues.

Comment: I think you just have to do two operations, create the file in the new folder then remove the file from the old folder. see https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/v2/developers_guide_protocol#MovingIntoFolders ...Good Luck

Comment: Yes tried that the problem is its the same file, so when i remove it it removes both because they have the same ID just different parents, the v3 documentation says this is possible, "Collections allow a resource to maintain a "many to many" relationship with each other." not sure if this applies to entries, but assume it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To copy/ move a file into a folder do the following:

```
$service = Zend_Gdata_Docs::AUTH_SERVICE_NAME;
$client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient($gUser, $gPass, $service); 
$docs = new Zend_GData_Docs($client);

$link = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/documents/private/full/spreadsheet:0AUFNVEpLOVg2U0E";
$entry = $docs->getDocumentListEntry($link);
// Folder (Collection you want to move to)
$folder = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/folders/private/full/folder%asdsad";
// Move
$data = $docs->insertDocument($entry, $folder);
```

Now some issues are:

1. It seem to make **reference** copy only, this means its still the same document only it has an extra category and parent link (so its now in two places). This may explain it better: https://groups.google.com/forum/embed/?place=forum/google-documents-list-api#!topic/google-documents-list-api/OrLi2JCINw4

I am sure there must be a way to do it "cleaner"/better but at least it moves it for now.